# Why running the same piece of VBA code takes different amount of time?

Tags: vba, excel

I am running the same piece of VBA code in Excel in two different ways.
1. Original way: click a command button which calls the sub.
2. Call the sub from a macro in a different workbook by using Application.Run.

I put a timer to measure how long it takes to run only the code in the sub. For the first way, the time taken is 319.36 seconds while for the second way the time taken is just 2.89 seconds.

How can this be explained?

Below is the code. In general, what it does is change a value in stsheet which is the active sheet when the sub is called, then copy and paste some values between different sheets.

```
Sub CopyPaste()

time1 = Timer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

stsheet = ActiveSheet.Name


Sheets("A1").Select
Range("F6:AA25").ClearContents

Sheets("A2").Select
Range("F6:S25").ClearContents


For I = 1 To 20
    Sheets(stsheet).Select
    Range("A20").Value = I

    Sheets("B").Select
    Range("u26:v30").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("d26").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets(stsheet).Select

    If Range("m34").Value = 0 Then
        Exit For
    End If

    For J = 1 To 22
        Sheets(stsheet).Select
        Range("A22").Value = J

        Range("y47").Value = Range("E101")

        Range("Y47").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("M1").Select
        Range("F6").Offset((I - 1), J - 1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

    Next J

    For K = 1 To 14
        Sheets(stsheet).Select
        Range("t52").Value = K

        Range("y48").Value = Range("E201")

        Range("y48").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("M2").Select
        Range("F6").Offset((I - 1), K - 1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

    Next K
 Next I

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox Timer - time1

End Sub
```

Comment: Something to do with which workbook is active when the code runs?  What does the code do?  It would be more useful to include the actual code in your post.

Comment: Over one hundred time quicker! That both amazing and concerning, is the code running successfully in both cases? And is doing the exact same thing?

Comment: Is the Excel sheet visible in both cases?

Comment: @TimWilliams , I've included the sub which is called by both the button and the macro.

Comment: @GaryEvans : It is concerning, but the results appear to be the same for both runs.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The Excel sheet is visible in both cases.

Comment: When running the second (quick) method, does the workbook that is calling the sub have the same data in (i.e. Sheets `A1` and `A2` with the same data set in?

Comment: The workbook that is calling the sub doesn't have any data. It just contains a macro which copies some values from another workbook and paste it into the main workbook which contains Sheets A1 and A2. Then run the CopyPaste sub in the main workbook.

Comment: Does the macro that calls this one have `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`?

Comment: If so add it to the beginning of this macro also, after `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and see if it speeds up. Just remember to change it back to automatic (if required) before the end of the sub.

Comment: No, it doesn't have `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`. But it has `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, which the sub above also has. I tried commenting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in the macro that calls the sub above and the time taken to run the sub above becomes 339.91 sec. So this could be the cause of the difference in running time but it doesn't make sense to me since the sub also contains this line.

Comment: Can you add the calculation manual to the beginning of this macro and see what the time difference is?

Comment: The time becomes 0.62 seconds.

Comment: Has that fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If this is taking ages try making calculation manual whilst the macro runs. Just remember to revert back to automatic (if required) at the end, like so.

```
Sub CopyPaste()

time1 = Timer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    *your code here*

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim. This makes it a lot faster. It's just that the initial concern was trying to understand why the second method is a lot faster than the original method and making sure that the code has been successfully run using the second method.

Comment: Without seeing the other macro it is hard to tell why one way is so much slower than the other. There is a lot of copying and pasting (which should always be avoided if possible!) and one way could be using up more system memory than the other, making it slower or faster. From the information in your question there would be too many variables to pinpoint the cause, so I opted for a solution to the speed, rather than an explanation as to why :)